# Can't fetch data from API in SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, fetch, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to display data I request by fetch from API. Everything works well except fetch.

This is my component named `Items.svelte`:

```html
<script>
  let items = [];

  async function load({ fetch }) {
    const url = "../r/api/items/all";
    let res = await fetch(url);

    if (res.ok) {
      return {
        props: {
          items: await res.json(),
        },
      };
    }
    return {
      status: res.status,
      error: new Error(),
    };
  }
</script>

{#each items as item}
  <header>
    <h2>{item.title}</h2>
    <p>{item.body}</p>
  </header>
{/each}
```

This is `App.svelte`:

```html
<script>
  import Items from '$lib/Items.svelte';
</script>
    
<Items />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation ---> https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading

You are missing the **context="module"** script section. It should be :

```
<script context="module">
    export async function load({ fetch }) {
        let res = await fetch('../r/api/items/all');

        if (res.ok) {
            return {
                props: {
                    items: await res.json()
                }
            };
        }
        return {
            status: res.status,
            error: new Error()
        };
    }
</script>


<script>
    export let items = []
</script>    

{#each items as item}
    <header>
        <h2>{item?.title}</h2>
        <p>{item?.body}</p>
    </header>
{/each}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but only if I run this code directly in App.svelte. When I put it in the separate component it won't work. That is the question.

Comment: Do you have any error in DevTools console ?

Comment: Nope. And I don't see any requests to the db in the terminal and DevTools console

Comment: Strange :)
Could you upload it to public github repo. I will try it locally and try to help ;)

Comment: Also, could you show content of your '../r/api/items/all' file and where it's located.
Maybe it's just a path issue as Items component is nested in $lib and App.svelte is not. So using ../ means one level up but from $lib it's maybe ../../ (two levels up)

Comment: One moment. With const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' it won't work too

Comment: This means that it's not reaching your own json.
A tip is to use hooks.js (or ts) and implement function handle({ request, resolve })
to console.log the request and response.
This help a lot to see exactly what's happening behind the scene

Answer (score 3):

In the docs (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/loading) it says: "A component that defines a page or a layout can export a load function that runs before the component is created."

You can't use load from a component, only from a page or layout.

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67429568/1390405