# How to Fetch Data inside SvelteKit Component that Is Not a Page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

*SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.324*

I have a SvelteKit component that is used in multiple places in my app, and it needs to fetch its own data from one of my endpoints.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422216/sveltekit-load-not-called-from-component-but-works-as-a-page) that states I can't have a `load` function unless it's a page. Assuming I cannot make this a page and import it into another page, I need to be able to fetch data into this component on its own.

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { onMount } from 'svelte'
import type { Aircraft } from '$lib/models'
  
let aircrafts: Aircraft[]

onMount(async() => {
  aircrafts = await (await fetch('/aircrafts')).json()
  console.log(aircrafts) //<-- This works
})
</script>
  
<p>{aircrafts.length} Aircraft</p> //<-- undefined Aircraft
```

My `/aircrafts` endpoint returns data just fine, and the `console.log` shows the data. But down in my HTML, `aircrafts.length` shows `undefined Aircraft`.

I assume this is because `onMount` happens after the props are set and the data isn't actually getting updated.

How can I pull data into a standalone component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you're attempting to display `aircrafts.length` before your data query has a chance to resolve. And since `aircrafts` is not reactive, your paragraph does not re-render when your promise finally *does* resolve.

The cleanest and most Svelte-like way to address this issue would be to make use of an [`{#await}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-await) block:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import type { Aircraft } from '$lib/models'
  
let aircrafts: Aircraft[]

async function getAircrafts() {
  const result = await fetch('/aircrafts')
  return result.json()
}
</script>

{#await getAircrafts()}
  <p>Loading aircrafts...</p>
{:then aircrafts}
  <p>{aircrafts.length} Aircraft</p>
{:catch error}
  <p>Error loading aircrafts: {error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

Note that the `onMount` block is unnecessary, as you do not have to wait for any content being mounted before you fetch your data. As a matter of fact, you want to start your fetch operation ASAP.

Comment: Wow, this is way more elegant than what I was doing. I really like it. Thank you!

Comment: *"And since `aircrafts` is not reactive"* - is there a SvelteKit config/mode where that's true? For the "basic start template" I think it's not?

Answer (score 14):

This issue you are having is that you need to get the data asynchronously and **THEN** render it to the page. Svelte makes this easy with the `await` markups helper.

The example case looks like this:

```js
{#await promise}
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then number}
    <p>The number is {number}</p>
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

The `number` in the above example is the *result* of the resolved promise.

So you your markup, you can try this:

```
<script lang="ts">

  async function getAircrafts() {
    const res = await fetch('/aircrafts');
    const values = await res.json();

    return values;
  }
  
  // NOTE await not used here! 
  let aircraftsPromise = getAircrafts();

</script>
  
{#await aircraftsPromise }
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then aircrafts}
    <p>{aircrafts.length} Aircraft</p>
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

What this does is give you a UI state for while the promise is running, as `aircraftsPromise`, then a state that passes the *result* of that promise for use in the markup, in `aircrafts`. Any errors hit the third UI state and get rendered.

In the `{:then ... }` block you are interacting with the resolved values, which is your array that you are looking for. You can then do whatever you want with it.

**EDIT** I forgot to link to the documentation on this. [Official Svelte docs on the await blocks are here.](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks)

**EDIT 2**

After revisiting this and also needing something similar in a project, I came across a way to add reactivity to the promise using an IIFE. This takes advantage of the svelte syntax to update the value of the promise based on a change in parameter used to calculate the promise, for example if you needed to update state based on an ID for an aircraft.

```
<script lang="ts">

  export let id: string; // Mutating this will cause function below to re-run

  $: aircraftPromise = (async function getAircraftById(aircraftID: string) {
    // Asuming API has a route for '/aircrafts/id'
    // and 'id' is a url path param
    const res = await fetch('/aircrafts/' + aircraftID);
    const value = await res.json();

    return value;
  // Note IIFE call with id variable after closing the function below
  // This makes the promise reactive based on 'id'
  })(id)  
    
</script>
  
{#await aircraftsPromise }
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then aircrafts}
    <p>{aircrafts.length} Aircraft</p>
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

This allows the entire component to be reactive to the `id` prop and provides a location for loading state display to take place easily. I've also found many other situations where the same pattern applies.

Comment: Your answer is essentially the same as the other. I had to flip a coin and pick one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: All good, although I was the first to post ;) More importantly though, wanted to help you get going.

Comment: Thanks you. very good answer. The reactive method is also interesting.

Comment: Does the `await` markup work with SSR? On the client side does svelte need to fetch data again?

Comment: @Tacaza now that Sveltekit introduced streaming of promises, I'm not sure if that works. It should still work as intended but will require some experimentation to understand.

Answer (score 3):

While both answers show using `{#await}` to display the value after it was fetched, this might give the impression that it's the only way and the main problem would be that the variable `aircrafts` is not reactive. There might be a SvelteKit configuration/mode where that's the case and the value wouldn't be updated after changing that I'm not aware of..? I just checked this in a new `@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.350` project `(@sveltejs/adapter-auto@1.0.0-next.50)` and the value is reactive

Since `let aircrafts` is initialized with `undefined`, `aircrafts.length` can't be accessed and I wonder why you don't get an error *"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"* which could be solved by using one of these options

```
{aircrafts?.length ?? ''}

{aircrafts ? aircrafts.length : ''}

{#if aircrafts}{aircrafts.length}{/if}
```

The `{#await}` block comes in handy if a different loading state should be shown and/or an error be handled visually. And if the value should only be displayed and not modified. Notice that the variable is scoped to the `{#await}` block [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c6885bc9ed5c481eb7a1762c6566291a?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>

    let todos // 'forever' undefined

    async function fetchTodos() {       
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
        return await response.json()
    }
</script>

{#await fetchTodos() then todos}
    <h1>{todos.length} todos!</h1>
{/await}

<button on:click={() => console.log(todos)}>log todos</button>
```

This would be an alternative if the value is also needed in the script block

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    let todos

    async function initTodos() {        
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
        todos = await response.json()
    }
</script>

{#await initTodos() then whatever}
    <h1>{todos.length} todos!</h1>
{/await}
```

In case that just the length of the value should be filled in the gap when it's available

```
<p>{*length when loaded*} Aircraft</p>
```

I probably wouldn't choose the `{#await}` variant [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f268a86113424b33a62decb09812e5e7?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    let todos
    
    onMount(async() => {
        todos = await fetchTodos()
    })

    async function fetchTodos() {
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
        return await response.json()        
    }
</script>

<h1>{todos ? todos.length : ''} todos!</h1>

<h1>{todos?.length ?? ''} todos!</h1>

<h1>{#if todos}{todos.length}{/if} todos!</h1>

<h1>{#await fetchTodos() then todos}{todos.length}{/await} todos!</h1>
```

Comment: You make some great points, thank you! I actually did end up needing `aircrafts` to be reactive so that I could update it after the initial `getAircrafts()` function loads. I was also able to eliminate the `.length` issue simply by initializing when declaring: `let aircrafts: Aircraft[] = []`

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Yes, starting with `let aircrafts = []` works too. It could be argued though, that the visual switch from zero to the final value is not optimal and if the zero is displayed, you can't tell if it's still loading or if that's the final fetched value and, if not handled otherwise, you'd also see the 0 if the value couldn't be fetched

Answer (score 2):

With [these changes made to `load()`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5748), components can access their page's server-side loaded data through `$page.data` (using the `page` store from `$app/stores`) everywhere, making the entire call to `fetch()` inside `onMount()` unnecessary.

Your `/aircrafts/+page.svelte` file just needs a neighbouring `/aircrafts/+page.server(.js/.ts)` file that exports a load function returning your `aircrafts` iterable. See [up-to-date docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load).

Comment: Imagine, in the page, someone selects an item from a drop-down, which makes a variable on the page change, which then causes another component on the page to have a different id... the component might need to fetch data for that identifier.  One might argue that one should create a page instead of a component for this, but it isn't unimaginable for someone to want to do this.